# Using ALAssetsLibrary, open a specific album straightaway

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, iphone-developer-program

I am using `ALAssetsLibrary` in my app. 
After getting images from camera,I am saving them in a separate folder in the Library.

The way I am doing it for now is calling the `ALAssetsLibrary` after dismissing camera through `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`. 
What I want is to open that particular saved images folder directly instead of selecting picking album first. 
Using `ELCImagePickerController` from Github actually takes through whole library first and then you select an album.

Comment: couald you explain a little. kinda confused with your question.

Comment: thanks for reply Superman, I actually want to open a specific album straight-away. So for eg., when the library opens we have to select an album, say 'Saved Images' and in that album there are some Images. I'd like to skip the select album part from library and call 'Saved Images' view straight on, where it shows the Images (with all the assets count).

Is that making sense?

thanks

Comment: Where are the images from the saved album are from? From the nsdocumentdirectory?

Comment: The images are taken from the camera itself then gets saved through 'writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum'.

Comment: Superman, it would be great if you refer to this Github example:
https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

thanks

Comment: anyone figure this out? i need to do the same thing (display images ONLY from the custom album i created from my app). @Samapple007 did you figure out a work around?  thanks!

Comment: Kindly share it if someone did this.